# Strip cookies for static files and set a long cache expiry time Varnish 3.0

Tags: cookies, varnish

I am using Varnish 3.0 and want to strip cookies for static files. Below is the code I am using but it is some how not working. Can any body please help?

```
 if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)") {
                    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
                    set beresp.ttl   = 1d;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there is a `$`missing in your code please use this code below.

```
 if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.ttl   = 1d;
}
```